# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaT'

Tags: python, datetime, youtube-data-api, invalidation

I am working on the change of users opinions towards some YouTube videos. So I have for each user a csv file where I have stored his comments, polarities and date of publishing each comment. The task is to calculate alpha, which refers to the average of changing opinion during a period. But I have faced a problem.
follow is my script

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def parse(mydate):
d,m,y=map(int,mydate.split('-'))
return date(d,m,y)

path = r'C:/Users/dell/project/script/base v2'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
nfile=len(filenames)
Alphaa=[]
for k in range(0,nfile):
pd1=pd.read_csv(filenames[k])
dfa=[]
for i in range(len(pd1)-1):
 date1=pd.to_datetime(pd1['publishedAt'][i:i+1])
 date2=pd.to_datetime(pd1['publishedAt'][i+1:i+2])

 date11=date1.to_string(index = False)
 date21=date2.to_string(index = False)
 date1=str(pd.DataFrame(pd1['publishedAt'][i:i+1]))
 date2=str(pd.DataFrame(pd1['publishedAt'][i+1:i+2]))
 duration=abs((parse(date21)-parse(date11)).days)

 p1=pd1['polarity'][i]
 p2=pd1['polarity'][i+1]
 diff=p2-p1
 if diff == 0:
       
   alph="NULL"
   UserOpinion="NULL"
   
 else:
     
   alph= duration/diff
   UserOpinion=alph*p1
   
 dfa.append(alph)
Alphaa.append(dfa)
```

and this is the traceback error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9704e3a864cf> in <module>
 54      date1=str(pd.DataFrame(pd1['publishedAt'][i:i+1]))
 55      date2=str(pd.DataFrame(pd1['publishedAt'][i+1:i+2]))
---> 56      duration=abs((parse(date21)-parse(date11)).days)
 57 
 58      p1=pd1['polarity'][i]

<ipython-input-9-9704e3a864cf> in parse(mydate)
 36 from datetime import date, timedelta
 37 def parse(mydate):
---> 38     d,m,y=map(int,mydate.split('-'))
 39     return date(d,m,y)
 40 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaT'
```

I have tried to change the result's form into float but it does not work. any help please?

Comment: Did you try to check the value of `mydate`? Does it make sense to you that the error occurs? When the value is `NaT`, what integer do you think should result from the conversion? Why?

Answer (score 0):

int() method takes an integer literal,  like int('36'). Here, you pass 'Nat' to int() so the error occurs.
You have to check the value of mydate before to cast it.